# Enforce type safety of a value of a generic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

How can i use generics in a way to enforce the type of a value to be of a specific kind?

```
// An example array
const testArr = [
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Spaghetto', // NOTE: Type 'string' here
    shouldNotWork: 3.14, // NOTE: Type 'number' here
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Bread',
    shouldNotWork: 3.14,
  },
];
```

This is what i tried to be my mapping function, but i have to append `as V2` to make TS not complain :/

```
type Mapping<T, U> = (val: T, i: number, arr: T[]) => U;

interface Option<T> {
  value: T;
  label: string; // <- NOTE: Type string is required
}

const typeToOption = <
  T,
  K1 extends keyof T,
  K2 extends keyof T,
  V2 extends T[K2] & string // <- NOTE: 'string' union here to match
>(
  valueK: K1,
  labelK: K2,
): Mapping<T, Option<T[K1]>> => (item: T): Option<T[K1]> => ({
  value: item[valueK],
  label: item[labelK] as V2,
});
```

I want TS to allow me this

```
const result = testArr.map(typeToOption('id', 'name'));
```

...but not this one

```
const result = testArr.map(typeToOption('id', 'shouldNotWork'));
```

How do i make TS complain about the latter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to type `typeToOption()` like this:

```
const typeToOption = <
  T extends Record<K2, string>,
  K1 extends keyof T,
  K2 extends keyof T,
>(
  valueK: K1,
  labelK: K2,
): Mapping<T, Option<T[K1]>> => (item: T): Option<T[K1]> => ({
  value: item[valueK],
  label: item[labelK],
});
```

TypeScript lets you do some amount "circular" type constraints in generic parameters.  So in this case, instead of specifying `V2` at all (since it wasn't doing any work), we just require that `T extends Record<K2, string>`, which means that the type `T` must have a `string` valued property at the key `K2`.  This is enough to give you the behavior you're asking for:

```
const result = testArr.map(typeToOption('id', 'name')); // okay

const result = testArr.map(typeToOption('id', 'shouldNotWork')); // error
// [ts] Argument of type '"id"' is not assignable to 
// parameter of type '"shouldNotWork"'.
```

Although the error is a bit bewildering, at least it's an error.  (If it matters: the type inference failure causes funny things to happen.  `T` falls back to `Record<'shouldNotWork', string>`, equivalent to `{shouldNotWork: string}`, and `keyof T` is only `'shouldNotWork'`, and therefore `K1 extends`'shouldNotWork'`.  Oh well.)

Hope that helps; good luck!